# Why does not catalyst die only once in a chained action?

Tags: perl, catalyst

Consider the following actions:

```
sub get_stuff :Chained('/') :PathPart('stuff') :CaptureArgs(1) {
  my ($self,$c,$stuff_id) = @_;
  die "ARRRRRRGGGG";
}

sub view_stuff :Chained('get_stuff') :PathPart('') :Args(0){
  die "DO'H";
}
```

Now if you request '/stuff/314/' , you'll get

```
Error: ARRRRG in get_stuff at ...

Error: DO'H in view_stuff at ...
```

Is there a reason why not just throw the error at the first failing chain link?

Why is catalyst trying to carry on the chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the answer as to 'why' but I presume it was done that way to give flexibility.

You should probably catch the error with eval (or preferably something like [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try%3a%3aTiny) or [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch)) and call `$c->detach` if you want to stop processing actions.

Answer (score 1):

[Catalyst::Plugin::MortalForward](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aMortalForward)

Comment: Welcome on SO. Maybe you should add some explanation from the link you provided, your answer will be useless if the link breaks. You could even copy paste the proper information in your answer. You can use "edit" to add more information. Please also look at the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer may be outdated. Catalyst can die early, when the application's config key `abort_chain_on_error_fix` is set.

```
__PACKAGE__->config(abort_chain_on_error_fix => 1);
```

See the documentation about [Catalyst configurations](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst#CONFIGURATION). It also states, that this behaviour may be standard in future.

Answer (score 0):

Cucabit is right, detach is the way to go. As to the why, normally in a perl process, 'die' stops the process. In Catalyst you don't want that. If for instance you run your Catalyst app under FastCGI, you spawn one or more standalone processes that handle multiple requests. If the first request would kill the process itself, the web server would have to respawn the FastCGI process in order to be able to handle the next call. I think for that, Catalyst catches 'die' (its used a lot as the default 'do_something() or die $!') and turns it into an Exception.

You could also end the process with 'exit' I guess, but you end up with the same problems as above, killing the process. 
What you can of course do is create your own 'die' method that logs the error passed with the default log object and then calls detach or something. it should also be possible to redefine the Catalyst exception handling as anything is possible with Catalyst :)

Comment: There's many layers where catalyst has a chance to catch die. Continuing the evaluation of the chained actions is clearly a choice.